# ESAPI throwing org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException when trying to log a warning

Tags: java, spring, esapi

We've added a filter to our spring webapp that checks all incoming requests for anything that could cause an XSS vulnerability. However, when it tries to write to the log, we get the following stack trace:

```
com.blah.blah.web.controllers.ExceptionLoggingController - ERROR: Exception: code=500,uri=/post.html,servlet=dispatch,class=org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException,from=1.2.3.4,message=Request processing failed; nested exception is org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Classname cannot be null or empty. HTTPUtilities type name cannot be null or empty.
org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Classname cannot be null or empty. HTTPUtilities type name cannot be null or empty.
    at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:105)
    at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.httpUtilities(ESAPI.java:121)
    at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.currentRequest(ESAPI.java:70)
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.JavaLogFactory$JavaLogger.log(JavaLogFactory.java:308)
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.JavaLogFactory$JavaLogger.warning(JavaLogFactory.java:242)
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder.canonicalize(DefaultEncoder.java:181)
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder.canonicalize(DefaultEncoder.java:120)
    at com.blah.blah.web.MyFilter.removeXSS(MyFilter.java:26)
```

I have ESAPI.properties on the classpath, that seems to be otherwise working, that does have the "missing" class configured:

```
ESAPI.HTTPUtilities=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultHTTPUtilities
```

And DefaultHTTPUtilities is on the classpath as well.

Comment: Maybe the ESAPI.properties is in multiple locations. Can you remove a property that you know is working and see that it checks if your change is picked up by ESAPI library.

Comment: Can you run the application on your local machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out I was also importing a library called opensaml (as a dependency of some other dependency). This library has its own implementation of SecurityConfiguration, which is the interface ESAPI uses to load configuration. For some reason the opensaml implements nearly all the methods to just return null or 0:

```
package org.opensaml;
/**
 * Minimal implementation of OWASP ESAPI {@link SecurityConfiguration}, providing the support used within OpenSAML.
 */
public class ESAPISecurityConfig implements SecurityConfiguration {
    /** Constructor. */
    public ESAPISecurityConfig() {
    }
    // snip...
    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    public String getHTTPUtilitiesImplementation() {
        return null;
    }
    // snip....
}
```

In a class called DefaultBootstrap, this was getting executed somewhere during the startup of my application, which overrides ESAPI's default implementation:

```
protected static void initializeESAPI() {
    ESAPI.initialize("org.opensaml.ESAPISecurityConfig");
}
```

I couldn't get rid of the opensaml library, so I had to change my code so that before I invoke ESAPI, I override it back to the default implementation:

```
        ESAPI.initialize("org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration");
        value = ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Suresh's comment...Toward that end, look at wherever you captured stdout and look for "Attempting to load ESAPI.properties" and follow that trail. It should look something like this:

```
Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via file I/O.
Attempting to load ESAPI.properties as resource file via file I/O.
Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: /home/kww/Code/GitHub/kwwall/esapi-java-legacy/ESAPI.properties
Found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: /home/kww/Code/GitHub/kwwall/esapi-java-legacy/target/test-classes/esapi/ESAPI.properties
Loaded 'ESAPI.properties' properties file
```

And them make sure that it is loading ESAPI.properties from where you expected it to be loaded.

Comment: And if you have questions about how the ESAPI.properties file is located, you can find some details about that here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639314/location-of-owasp-esapi-file-in-maven-project-web/17644433#17644433

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have SAML library in my project which is initializing the ESAPI with its specific security configuration(ESAPISecurityConfig).

The ESAPISecurityConfig always returns null when requested for HTTPUtilitiesImplementation.

```
 /** {@inheritDoc} */
    public String getHTTPUtilitiesImplementation() {
        return null;
    }
```

In DefaultBootstrap.class in saml library. It is clear that the intialization of ESAPI would happen it there is no system property available for the key "org.owasp.esapi.SecurityConfiguration".

```
    /**
     * Initializes the OWASPI ESAPI library.
     */
    protected static void initializeESAPI() {
        Logger log = getLogger();
        String systemPropertyKey = "org.owasp.esapi.SecurityConfiguration";
        String opensamlConfigImpl = ESAPISecurityConfig.class.getName();
        
        String currentValue = System.getProperty(systemPropertyKey);
        if (currentValue == null || currentValue.isEmpty()) {
            log.debug("Setting ESAPI SecurityConfiguration impl to OpenSAML internal class: {}", opensamlConfigImpl);
            System.setProperty(systemPropertyKey, opensamlConfigImpl);
            // We still need to call ESAPI.initialize() despite setting the system property, b/c within the ESAPI class
            // the property is only evaluated once in a static initializer and stored. The initialize method however
            // does overwrite the statically-set value from the system property. But still set the system property for 
            // consistency, so other callers can see what has been set.
            ESAPI.initialize(opensamlConfigImpl);
        } else {
            log.debug("ESAPI SecurityConfiguration impl was already set non-null and non-empty via system property, leaving existing value in place: {}",
                    currentValue);
        }
```

So to prevent SAML from initializing ESAPI we can either set the below before the control reaches SAML. I have added it in a static block in our application which we use to inject few properties to spring environment.

```
String systemPropertyKey = "org.owasp.esapi.SecurityConfiguration";
String defaultConfigImpl = DefaultSecurityConfiguration.class.getName();
**System.setProperty(systemPropertyKey, defaultConfigImpl );**
ESAPI.initialize(defaultConfigImpl);
```

Or you can add below property in your runtime arguments which prevents SAML from creating its own implementation. When we call the methods on ESAPI for the first time in our application a default instance would be created automatically.

```
-Dorg.owasp.esapi.SecurityConfiguration=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration
```